# gnuplot badly renders heat map on uneven grid

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap

I am trying to plot a heat map of 3D results, a f(x,y) function, obtained on an uneven grid.
The plot I obtain gives me some ugly empty spaces at the top of the graph.
Below are minimal scripts to reproduce the issue I am facing.

```
#Generate some dummy data
f(x,y) = sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
set table
set samples 1000
set output "table.dat"
splot [0:10][0:10] f(x,y)
```

The plotting script :

```
# plot it
set term x11
set out
set pm3d map 
splot [1:5] [0:2] "table.dat" u ($1):($2/$1):($3)
```

Since the y-axis value depends on the x-axis, the grid is now even. As can be seen in the following figure gnuplot fails to fill-up some space close to the top border of the plot. Changing the axis limits doesn't help.

[sample impage plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8evfM.png)

Any idea how to fill-up the white triangles and make this plot look nicer ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: it's hard to imagine how exactly it should **look nicer**

Comment: Hi there, this is right. I meant without the white triangles at the top. There is some data to be plotted here, it should be colored.

Comment: If you want to fill in the data points between your samples you have to use interpolation, which you can do with `set dgrid3d`. Also, note that your table has very fine resolution in `x` (1000 points), but very poor resolution in `y` (10 points). Interpolation will work better with a finer mesh (`set isosamples 1000`).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I can't change the original data sampling, the above script is just an illustration. Unfortunately, dgrid3d does not seem to handle correctly the situation, I think the problem comes from the fact that the y-axis depends on the x-axis :   u ($1):($2/$1):($3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dgrid3d` for 2-d interpolation. With your `using` specification `($1):($2/$1):($3)` the domain where you have data points is very irregular. It helps to tell `dgrid3d` that you are interested only in a small rectangle by setting all other values to NaN. For example:

```
set pm3d map 
set dgrid3d 100,100 qnorm 4
splot [1:5] [0:2] "table.dat" u ($1 >= 1 && $1 <= 5 ? $1 : 1/0):($2/$1 > 0 && $2/$1 < 2 ? $2/$1 : 1/0):3
```

[image]

You will have to experiment with the various options of `dgrid3d` to get a reasonable interpolation.

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks for this trick ! Just a shame that dgrid3d does not do this based on the plot ranges.